# If $f^{-1}(f(E)) = E$ for all $E \subseteq X$ then $f(A-B) = f(A) - f(B)$ for all $A,B\subseteq X$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$.

Prove: If $f^{-1}(f(E)) = E$ for all $E \subseteq X$, then $f(A-B) = f(A) - f(B)$ for all $A,B\subseteq X$.

Note: $A-B = \{x: x\in A, \text{ but } x\notin B \}$.

Proof: Suppose $f^{-1}(f(E)) = E$ for all $E \subseteq X$. Let $y \in f(A-B)$. Then $\exists x \in A-B$ such that $y = f(x)$. Since $x \in A-B$, $x\in A$, but $x\notin B$. Then $f(x)\in f(A)$, but $f(x) \notin f(B)$. Thus, $y = f(x) \in f(A) - f(B)$.

On the other hand, let $y \in f(A)-f(B)$. Then $y \in f(A)$, but $y \notin f(B)$. Then $\exists x \in A$ such that $y = f(x)$. Since $y \notin f(B)$, $x \notin B$. Thus, $x \in A -B$, so $y = f(x) \in f(A-B)$.

My proof that $f(A-B) = f(A) - f(B)$ didn't use the antecedent at all. So I'm wondering if I need to use it directly.

Comment: In the first half of your proof, what if there is a point $p$ in $B$ such that $f(p) = f(x)$?  That would make $f(x)$ an element of $f(B)$.

Comment: @DisplayName: You're right. I suppose, if I could show that f is injective that would take care of that issue, correct?

Comment: Yes, that would take care of it.

Comment: Regarding injectivity: if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, what can you say about $f^{-1}(f(\{x_1\}))$?

Comment: @GregMartin: Then $f^{-1}(f(\{x_1\})) = \{x_2\}$

Comment: Actually you can conclude that $f^{-1}(f(\{x_1\})) \supseteq \{x_1,x_2\}$. Given the assumption on $f$, what does that tell you about $x_1$ and $x_2$?

Comment: @GregMartin That they are equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y\in f(A-B)$, then there exists some $x\in A-B$ such that $f(x)=y$. Note $x\in A$, therefore $f(x)=y\in f(A)$. But $f(x)$ may be not in $f(B)$.(why?)

Suppose it were true that $f(x)\in f(B)$.
 Then there exists some $x_0\in B$ such that $f(x_0)=f(x)$. Then consider the pre-image set of $f(x)$,

$$f^{-1}(f\{x_0\})=f^{-1}(f\{x\})\Rightarrow x_0=x\text{ (By assumption)}$$
Then contradiction arises.

Comment: I think you meant: But $f(x)$ may or may not be in $f(B)$.

Comment: If so, the answer to why would be like @DisplayName pointed out. There could be some point p in B such that $f(p) = f(x)$ which would make $f(x)$ in $f(B)$.

Comment: Yes, if the assumption is gone, then injectivity is not assured