# Why is this proof that $f(A-B)\subseteq f(A)-f(B)$ wrong?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Consider this part of Exercise 2.9 of Apostol's *Mathematical Analysis*:

> Let $f:S\to T$ be a function. Prove that d) $\to$ e), where:
>
> d) For all disjoint subsets of $A$ and $B$ of $S$, the images $f(A)$ and $f(B)$ are disjoint.
>
> e) For all subsets $A$ and $B$ of $S$ such that $B\subseteq A$, $f(A-B)=f(A)-f(B)$.

To prove e) we must show that

1. $f(A-B)\subseteq f(A)-f(B)$, and
2. $f(A)-f(B)\subseteq f(A-B)$.

In trying to show $1.$ I wrote the following:

> The set $f(A-B)$ consists of the $f(x)$ such that $x\in A-B$. This means that $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$, so $f(x)\in f(A)$ and $f(x)\notin f(B)$. Hence, $f(x)\in f(A)-f(B)$, and $f(A-B)\subseteq f(A)-f(B)$.

After proving $2.$ without having used d) or the fact that $B\subseteq A$, I realized that something was wrong. A proof of $1.$ involving both facts occurred to me after a while. The answer and some comments to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1930008/if-f-1fe-e-for-all-e-subseteq-x-then-fa-b-fa-fb-for-al), point to my mistake. However, I can't, for the life of me, understand what is my mistake.

What did I do wrong? How could I avoid this kind of mistake?

Comment: The part that is incorrect is $f(x) \notin f(B)$. There may be some other point $b \in B$ such that $f(x)=f(b)$ so that $f(x) \in f(B)$ even though $x \notin B$.

Comment: If you are not using the the property of $(d)$ to prove $(e)$ then it is irrelevant that $d\implies e$ because $e$ would be true regardless.  So, why does  $d\implies e$?

Comment: I think your proof for $1$ is fine, though you could make it explicit that you're using $(d)$ at the end of the second sentence. It's hard to say where you went wrong in proving the second part unless you show us what you did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What did I do wrong?

$x \notin B$ does not mean $f(x) \notin f(B)$.

For example, take $f : [2, 4) \to [4, 16)$ to be $f(x) = x^2$.

Then $-2 \notin [2,4)$ but $f(-2) = 4 \in f([2,4)) = [4,16)$.

EDIT:  For similar reasons, it's also not generally true that "$f(A-B)$ consists of the $f(x)$ such that $x \in A - B$."  If you view $f(A-B)$ as a set, then it *contains* the (set of all) $f(x)$ such that $x \in A-B$, but to say it *consists* of such $f(x)$ can be interpreted as meaning it *consists only of* such $f(x)$, which isn't necessarily true.

I think you were on the right track and thinking of the right tools to use, but it's possible the notation/naming caused confusion.  That's just my guess and maybe I'm wrong.

> How could I avoid this kind of mistake?

Practice, practice, more practice.  Making mistakes is an essential part of the learning process.

---

If there's any confusion in this problem in general I think it may arise from the fact that **the $A$ and $B$ in (d) aren't the same as the $A$ and $B$ in (e)**.  Here's a complete rough draft of a proof.  Will need cleaning up in some areas.

We want to prove (d) implies (e).  So, suppose we have $B \subseteq A \subseteq S$.  We want to show that $f(A) \setminus f(B) = f(A \setminus B)$.

Let $y \in f(A) \setminus f(B)$.  Then $y \in f(A)$ and $y \notin f(B)$.  Thus there is some $x \in A$ such that $f(x) = y$.  Also, since $y \notin f(B)$ then we must have $x \notin B$.  So $x \in A$ and $x \notin B$, which means $x \in A \setminus B$.  Thus, $f(x) \in f(A \setminus B)$.  This shows one set inclusion.

For the other set inclusion, let $z \in f(A \setminus B)$.  Then there is some $w \in A \setminus B$ such that $f(w) = z$.  Since $A \setminus B$ and $B$ are disjoint, then by part (d) we must have  that $f(A \setminus B)$ and $f(B)$ are disjoint.  Combining this with the fact that $f(w) \in f(A \setminus B)$ therefore tells us that $f(w) \notin f(B)$.  Furthermore, since $w \in A \setminus B$, then $w \in A$.  Thus, $f(w) \in f(A)$.  So $f(w) \in f(A)$ and $f(w) \notin f(B)$, giving us $f(w) \in f(A) \setminus f(B)$.  This shows the other set inclusion.

Comment: Given the context of the problem, if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint then $f(A)$ and $f(B)$ are disjoint. Since $x\in A-B$, and $A-B$ is disjoint from $B$ by definition, then $f(x)\in f(A)$ and $f(x)\notin f(B)$

Comment: @Turambar, I see what you're saying, but to show (d) implies (e), we want $B \subseteq A$.  So $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint.  We can apply what you've said to $A \setminus B$ and $B$, because those, as you've said, are disjoint.  The notation/naming does make things a little tricky here.

Comment: You have pinpointed the root of my problems in some proofs I've attempted recently. Thanks a lot for such a dedicated and complete answer, as well as for the encouragement.

Comment: @Drarp, no problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

It's not generally true that $f(A-B)=f(A)-f(B)$. Consider the unique function $f\colon\{1,2\}\to\{0\}$ and take $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{2\}$.

Then $f(A-B)=f(\{1\})=\{0\}$, whereas $f(A)-f(B)=\{0\}-\{0\}=\emptyset$.

This fails exactly where your mistake is: we can indeed have $f(A-B)\nsubseteq f(A)-f(B)$.

Saying that $y\in f(A-B)$ means $y=f(x)$, for some $x\in A$, $x\notin B$. Thus $y\in f(A)$, but this does not exclude $y\in f(B)$.

<sub>It would if the function is injective, but unfortunately this is not among the hypotheses.</sub>

Note that the example function does not satisfy property d, because $f(\{1\})=f(\{2\})=\{0\}$, but $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$ are disjoint.